# Изменение размера формы

Tags: delphi, resize, form

Как можно просто и без проблем запретить изменение размера форм, при этом установить стандартное (постоянное) значение?

Нашел, что можно так писать:

```
Constraints.MinHeight := 296;
Constraints.MinWidth := 442;
Constraints.MaxHeight := 296;
Constraints.MaxWidth := 442;
```

Но мне кажется, что для этого слишком много кода.

Подскажите, как быть?

Comment: 4 строчки - это не слишком много кода ))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В режиме конструктора формы поставьте соответствующие свойства `BorderStyle = bsSingle`, `BorderIcons - biMaximize = false`. Размеры ставьте хоть программно, хоть в конструкторе.

Answer (score 1):

Добавлю, пожалуй. Можно установить свойство AutoSize = true, и размер формы будет таким, чтобы в ней поместились все компоненты. Если размер компонента программно увеличивается, форма автоматически меняет свой размер.